# Prestashop v 1.5.6.2. menu issue after server migration

Tags: menu, content-management-system, prestashop, categories, product

Before i had problem with prestashop server and domain migration. I solved it, but now occurs another problem. After a domain call website display "homepage" of my prestashop, but after selecting any position from main menu it redirect me to right address but I recieve message, "Page not found".

any ideas why or how to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

If the SEO is enabled, you should try with SEO disabled.

if seo is allready disabled, activate the MODE_DEV in config/defines.inc.php :

change

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', false);
```

to

```
define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);
```

Then reload the page and see if there is some errors.
You can also look at you php error file.

Hope it help, cheers